# How can Paramiko work with Windows .log files?

Tags: windows, file, logging, paramiko

I am unable to use Paramiko command output for any commands with Windows .log associated files, which my application generates.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = SSH.exec_command("dir c:\scratch\junk.log /b")
```

Using standard ssh the above command works fine.

```
dir c:\scratch\junk.log /b
junk.log
```

It works if I specify a .txt file.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = SSH.exec_command("dir c:\scratch\junk.txt /b")
```

Comment: Did you try reading `stderr` to  check for errors?

Comment: with this...

error = stderr.readlines()
      print(error)

I get this...
[]

Comment: @Martin I am not seeing any errors, so do you have any advice? thanks